# Skeleton View usage in TableView

Tags: swift, xcode

I use Skeleton View for my animation and I have similar func like:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return articles?.articles.count ?? 10
}


func collectionSkeletonView(_ skeletonView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return articles?.articles.count ?? 10
}



func collectionSkeletonView(_ skeletonView: UITableView, cellIdentifierForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> ReusableCellIdentifier {
    return "articleCell" 
}


func collectionSkeletonView(_ skeletonView: UITableView, skeletonCellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell? {
    let cell = skeletonView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "articleCell", for: indexPath) as? ArticleCell
    
    if let article = articles?.articles[indexPath.row] {
       
        cell?.titleLabel.text = article.title
        cell?.urlLabel.text = article.source.name
        
  
        let imgURL = article.urlToImage
        cell?.imageIcon.loadImage(withUrl: imgURL ?? "")
        
        
      
    }
    
    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "articleCell", for: indexPath) as! ArticleCell
    
    if let article = articles?.articles[indexPath.row] {
       
        cell.titleLabel.text = article.title
        cell.urlLabel.text = article.source.name
        
  
        let imgURL = article.urlToImage
        cell.imageIcon.loadImage(withUrl: imgURL ?? "")
    }


    return cell
}
```

I tried to delete the TableVIew but it is arguing that due to protocol I have to have those two func from TableView

Is it okay to have the same operation as above, if no then
how to delete the TableView func?

Thanks

Comment: Note that in the sample code https://github.com/Juanpe/SkeletonView/blob/main/Example/TableView/ViewController.swift they implement both.

Comment: Yes, I guess there is no other options